# Bash a way of recording an immutable variable

Tags: bash

What I am trying to achieve is, when I release a piece of software it has his software version, (1.0, 1.1, etc.) Can I make a variable in bash that could not be edited once the user downloads my program?

I have something like:
`declare -r version=11`
If the final user opens vim as sudo/root he can easly edit this value, can bash provide something to work around this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: As long as the user has full control of the computer the software is on, you cannot prevent them from modifying it. What you're asking for is equivalent to the problem of copy protection, which nobody has ever solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of programming languages the term "immutable" means that a variable can not be modified after the first assignment. This is typically a constant.

What you are looking for is a way to make the whole program immutable. This can be done in the file system.

```
sudo chattr +i your-script
```

Now the script is immutable and it can not be changed by `vi` directly. But the user can remove the immutable flag in order to edit the file.